# How to get rid of extra quotes from the header when using Apache CSVParser

Tags: java, csv, parsing, apache-commons

I am trying to pull in a CSV file to validate against expected values. However, there is an issue with reading in the header row. Specifically, whatever is the first column header remains quoted which confuses the mappings.

Here is the method for reading in the file:

```
public boolean openCsv(File fileObject) {
    if (fileObject.exists()) {
        try {
            parser = CSVParser.parse(fileObject, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreHeaderCase());
            headers = parser.getHeaderMap();
            records = parser.getRecords();

            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot parse CSV file: " + fileObject.getName());
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem is, with the given header:

> "Company ID","Company Name","Company Website","Company Phone", ...

The header map and records list will always leave the first value as quoted:

> Error: IllegalArgumentException-Mapping for Company ID not found, expected one of [Company Name, Company Phone, Company Website, ..., ﻿"Company ID"]

I tried looping through the header and removing the quotes, but the quoted value is part of the mapping of the records too which means I'd have to loop and rebuild everything.

I have tried different values for CSVParse.parse but the problem remains.

Is there something I'm missing? I checked the Apache Commons JIRA board and no one else has reported this issue so I am inclined to think it's something I need to configure.

Since the columns vary from export to export, I cannot hardcode them and pass it to the parser. It needs to be dynamic.

Comment: From your error message it seems to be the other way round. `Mapping for Company ID not found` (no quote around Company ID); `expected one of ... "Company ID"]` (quoted). So it _expects_ quoted version but _gets_ the unquoted version?

Comment: @Vasan, Note that no other header has quotes. It's just the first one on the row that keeps quotes. So if I look for "Company Name" **with quotes**, it would fail. I really don't care if all the headers have quotes or not, but it must be consistent. Since the fields exportable are user-configured, I have no way of knowing what the first column is named. While I could probably hack together something with try/catch, if/else it seems like a lot of work due to one exception.

Comment: which version of the library do you use? Can you show us also part of the code where you use the header? (ex. read some fields from the row)

Comment: I don't get the same results, nothing has extra quotes for me.  What code is issuing the error message?  I don't believe that message comes from Commons CSV, it must come from some other code.  Please [edit] your post and include the COMPLETE stack trace (with all caused-by sections, code format) and indicate exactly which Java statement throws the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to replicate similar issue, if there is space before "Company ID" it gets quoted (but you would probably notice space before first column in the header, also the space would still be present in the mapping).

Then I noticed one more thing in your error message: "Company ID" is the last printed element of the mapping, even tough it should be first using alphabetical or "in file" order.

Next I remembered there are some "invisible" characters in unicode. For example: [zero width space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm), [(on wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) I've created test file with zero width space before "Company ID", and got exactly the same error message you show in your question:

> Mapping for Company ID not found, expected one of [Company Name, Company Phone, Company Website, ​"Company ID"]
>       at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord.get(CSVRecord.java:102)

The no break space is present in above message.

By the way, after finding this I've copied your error message and checked it for invisible characters. It seems there's an ["zero width no break space"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FEFF/index.htm) before "Company ID".

Probably you will have to parse the file and remove such characters from it - I don't know why something like that would find its way into a csv file.

Comment: Could be a UTF-8 BOM (`0xFEFF`)

Comment: @JimGarrison, that would explain how it appeared... probably file was created in notepad or some other editor that adds it by default. Thanks for pointing it

Comment: @JimGarrison and Kamil, you guys nailed it. The app than generated the export file was creating an UTF-8+BOM file. I switched the parser to `Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new BOMInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileObject)));` and it works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: @MivaScott save my day thanks. When someone finding dependency  for BOMInputStream [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.6)